# Spring Data HQL Parser unjustified used for native query

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have this query in my RepositoryBean:

```
Query(value = "TRUNCATE TABLE #{#entityName}", nativeQuery = true)
@Modifying
void truncateTable();
```

This used to work with Spring Boot 3.0.x. However, after upgrading to Spring 3.1.2 i receive an error from the HQL Parser because TRUNCATE is unknown:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.BadJpqlGrammarException: Line 1:0 mismatched input 'TRUNCATE' expecting {'(', DELETE, FROM, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, WITH}; Bad JPQL grammar [TRUNCATE TABLE CLEANUP_ENTITY_1]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.BadJpqlGrammarErrorListener.syntaxError(BadJpqlGrammarErrorListener.java:39)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.ProxyErrorListener.syntaxError(ProxyErrorListener.java:41)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser.notifyErrorListeners(Parser.java:543)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.DefaultErrorStrategy.reportInputMismatch(DefaultErrorStrategy.java:327)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.DefaultErrorStrategy.reportError(DefaultErrorStrategy.java:139)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.HqlParser.ql_statement(HqlParser.java:348)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.HqlParser.start(HqlParser.java:256)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.HqlQueryParser.parseQuery(HqlQueryParser.java:53)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.HqlQueryParser.parse(HqlQueryParser.java:63)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryParserSupport$ParseState.lambda$new$0(JpaQueryParserSupport.java:182)
```

It seems that the new Spring parser feature does not recognize the native query (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Spring-Data-2023.0-%28Ullman%29-Release-Notes). I have Hibernate Validator in my classpath. Maybe this is the problem.
Is this a bug or am i on the wrong track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a known Spring Data JPA bug. Try upgrading to Spring Boot 3.1.3 and if that doesn't help then you'll probably have to wait for this to be fixed:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/pull/3145

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Update to 3.1.3 didn't help. Can i somehow deactivate the query checking?

Comment: Not that I know. Perhaps you could bypass it by giving @NamedNativeQuery a go (the JPA one, rather than the Hibernate one): https://www.javaguides.net/2018/11/spring-data-jpa-namednativequery-namednativequeries-example.html

Comment: Rather than using #{#entityName}, if you use the actual table name, then hopefully that should sort it (I made some progress with it locally). I'm not sure it makes sense to use entityName with a native query anyway.

Comment: I tried to use the actual table name. However, i now run in an error i cant classify:
`org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: JDBC exception executing SQL [TRUNCATE TABLE ENTITY1] Method is only allowed for a query. Use execute or executeUpdate instead of executeQuery; SQL statement`

Comment: That's strange, I though that @Modifying would prevent that.

Comment: Don't ask me why, but the error disappeared. Now everything works. So, what i just had to do is elimnate the #{#entityName} and replace it with an explicit table name.